# How to tell if Android screen lock setting is set to None

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I need check if the Screen Lock setting is set to "None" (or not).

I am deploying an app that is being sent out to users on pre-configured tablets.

This pre-configuration is done manually by the tablet supplier.

One of the settings to pre-configure is to set the Screen lock to None (It would be a bad thing if the tablet reached the end user with the screen lock still enabled).

The last thing that the person configuring the device does is to start the app, where they will be able to see a check list to confirm that the settings have been set accordingly in order to help avoid any missed/incorrect settings.

The Screen Lock is the only setting that I have been unable to find a way to either read or set programmatically.

The tablets are rooted and running 4.2.2.

Assume that the end user is incapable of interacting in any way with the tablet - other than powering it on and reading the display.

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: Mike, thanks for the link. I'd already spent the day poring over it trying to find what I'm after. The Device Admin looks good for setting constraints on password and the like - I kind of need to go in the other direction and loosen the security a bit. I can't find anything on Device Admin that allows me to query or set the Screen lock setting. Unless you know of a specific call that I may have missed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to check if device is set to None?

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: I ended up amending the operating system build for the tablet and removing the screen lock code entirely (can't remember which app it was).  I am selling an app that comes pre-installed on a tablet,so I don't need to worry about it working on every device just the one that I am selling. If you are doing something similar I can go back and find out which app I removed from the o/s (it does require you to have access to the operating system image and know how to amend it).